# PYTHON строковые данные \xa0 <-- не получается удалить из строки. string.replace('\\xa0', "") не помогает

Tags: python, строки, парсер

Всем приветик. Если коротко - в строке получаемой из гугла (количество выдачи) появились специальные символы `\xa0`. Убрать их через функцию `string.replace` не получилось. Попробовал так же циклом при нахождении `'\'` не записывать данные, и, нет, это тоже не сработало.
Да и в целом с попытками как то работать с этим символом `'\'` - не получается. То функции объявляются не законченными, то еще что то.

Так что задача - нужно как то убрать `\xa0` из строчки

```
'Результатов: примерно 112\xa0000\xa0000 (0,67 сек.)\xa0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде работает =).

```
my_string = 'Результатов: примерно 112\xa0000\xa0000 (0,67 сек.)\xa0'.replace('\xa0', '')
print(my_string)
```

Вывод

```
Результатов: примерно 112000000 (0,67 сек.)
```

А при использовании цикла у вас скорее всего не получалось поскольку символ **\xa0** считается одним символом и пытаясь найти совпадение на **\** вы не получали нужного результата.

Comment: мне необходимо ивзлечь содержимое в интегер, и туда попадает кусок который значение, а не вывод строки. СТрока и у меня выводится правильно, мне значение нужно было.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.replace('\\xa0', "")
```

Это и не будет работать, потому что менять нужно `\xa0`, а не `\\xa0`. Ну и присваивать результат надо не забывать:

```
string = string.replace('\xa0', "")
```

В данном случае `\` не нужно экранировать, потому что это не символ `\` сам по себе, а наоборот обозначение, что дальше идёт специальный символ.

Comment: этот вариант не работает, потмоу что, вы не поверите, с него я начал.

Comment: У вас в заголовке вопроса несколько другой код приведён. Приведите все варианты которые вы пробовали в самом вопросе.